# scanf reading more than required

Tags: c

I am coding a program in C that requires the user to enter 3 inputs. I am using scanf to get the numbers:

```
printf("Enter the first value: ");
scanf("%lf", &eps);

while(eps < 0){
    printf("Epsilon must be positive. Choose a new value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &eps);
}
printf("Enter with the second value: ");
scanf("%lf ", &A);
while(A < 0){
    printf("A must be positive. Enter with a new value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &A);
}

if (A != 0){
    printf("Enter the third value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &w);

    while(w < 0){
        printf("w must be positive. Enter with a new value: ");
        scanf("%lf", &w);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the second input is required, I put a value and my scanf just ignore it and "asks for a new number" (I mean, if I enter 1, I need to enter 1 again so that this value is read). I haven't been using C for a while, but I remember that I had this problem before and used something like getch() or getchar() after the scanf so the problem didn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the complete minimal working example? What data type is eps, how is it declared and defined?

Comment: What do you mean? I enter 1 for epsilon, then it requires a value for A but I need to enter it twice so the value is read.

Comment: You should IMO include a minimal working code and the contents of your console when running the program. Otherwise any answer is a guesswork.

Comment: Like @PavelŠimerda said... show the rest of the code, what happens before the snipped pasted here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an unfortunate extra space character in the `scanf` format here:

```
scanf("%lf ", &A);
```

That will cause scanf to swallow all whitespace following the number, including the newline character and whitespace in the next line (which means that it will insist on reading another line.)

Remove the space and it should work ok.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
scanf("%lf ", &A);
       // ^-------- This space
```

Quoting [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html):

> A directive composed of one or more white-space characters shall be executed by reading input until no more valid input can be read, or up to the first byte which is not a white-space character, which remains unread.

After you enter your `A` value the first time, `scanf` is required to read more input until it reads a non-whitespace character. Thus you must enter *something* (besides whitespace) after your `A` value.